# How to permanently update a path variable in a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy

I'd like to know if there's a way to dynamically edit the lines in my scripts depending on a user input from an arcpy tool that I have created. the interface will allow the user to pick a file, then there's a boolean check to permanently change the default directory if the program was run later.

if you are familiar with arcpy:

```
def example():


  defaultPath="C:\\database.dbf"

  path=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)#returns a string of a directory
  userCheck=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)#returns a string "TRUE"/"FALSE"
  if path=="":
     path=defaultPath
```

The goal here is to change "defaultPath" permanently if "userCheck" is "TRUE". I think it's possible to do that with the use of classes? or do I need to have an "index" table and refer to it's cells (like an excel sheet).

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with `arcpy`, but in general I would store this sort of setting in a configuration file rather than trying to modify my program source.

Comment: would u suggest something specific

Comment: (1) Write the `defaultPath` value to a file. (2) Check for that file at startup and if it exists, read the `defaultPath` value back and use it.

Comment: makes sense but any preferd file format, and referral method . would be great if you set me up with more keywords, and materials to search online :)

Comment: See `ConfigParser` in the standard library. Per-user configuration files usually go in OS-specific places (`$HOME/.myscriptrc` in Unix, e.g.)